# Alternatives to "make it sound"

Tags: meaning, verbs

According to Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary "Sound" in the "Leo made it sound so easy. But it wasn't." is a linking verb to give a particular impression when heard or read about.

But I don't understand the meaning of "make it sound" yet? Is there an alternative way to say it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to say this is:

> "Leo made it **seem** so easy. But it wasn't."

Check this definition of [sound](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/sound) as an intransitive verb sense 9 or 10.

Answer (score 1):

**MAKE IT SOUND**

Consider a situation. You are dealing with some very difficult concept of physics, say for example Quantum Physics (as I find it too difficult). And you have attended two classes of two different teachers - say, A and B. Attending A's class you got more confused, but when you attended B's class, the concept started to make sense to you. The language was easy. Actually, B *"made it sound"* easy.

Does it make sense? I mean the term "make it sound"?